# Compare string that equals to asterisk

Tags: java, string, comparison

As mentioned above, how do i look for string that is equals to `*`?

I've tried this:

```
if (string.equals("*")) {
    return message;
}
```

The program just wont enter into the `if` statement. Could i know where did I went wrong?

Comment: There is *no such thing* as an "if-loop". Why don't you examine the value of `string` in the debugger to see if it really only contains a `*`?

Comment: `if("*".equals("*")){...}` worked fine for me. What is contained by `string` in your case?

Comment: If you don't pass the asterisk as a command line argument (see my answer), please post a working (or rather a compilable but "problem exposing") program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine, the code below returns `"happy"` to console, there's nothing wrong with using `.equal` on a String for `*`.

```
 public class NumberFun {
    static String string = "*";
    static String message = "happy";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(getMessage());
    }

    private static String getMessage() {
        if (string.equals("*")) {
            return message;
        }
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

Comment: strange, let me go debug and see where went wrong. thanks david :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `String` might have spaces. I would try by applying on `trim()`

```
if(string.trim().equals("*")){
        return message;
    }
```

Here is example:

```
String mytem ="*";

     if(mytem.equals("*"))
     {
         System.out.println("Hello");
     }
```

Output:

```
Hello
```

Comment: Nambari, i don't think that is the reason. I've tried that too. not working too. :(

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm going to place another bet: The String you are trying to compare is passed as a command line argument. But command line arguments are expanded by the shell (at least on Unix/Linux and the like). A single asterisk will for example expand to a list of files in the current directory. Your Java program (and even the JVM) has no chance to see the original input asterisk.

Print your String before doing the comparison. If my guess is true, enclose the command line argument in quotes to avoid shell expansion.